# MySQL query with AND and OR in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I am creating a student records search query. The school has three clubs (maths, english and science). What i want to do is to select student by the club they have joined in this order.
Student who are in
-- Maths Only
-- Maths and English only
-- Maths and Science Only
-- English Only
-- English and Science Only
-- Science Only

```
Student table (studentTB)

id | student_name | date_join
-----------------------------
 1 | Daniel Addo  | 2012-01-05
 2 |David Polles  | 2013-05-11
 3 | Grace Amorno | ---------
 4 | Zein Akill   | ---------

Club table (studentCLUB)

id | studentID | club
----------------------
1  | 1         | maths
2  | 1         | science
3  | 2         | science
4  | 2         | english
5  | 3         | science
6  | 4         | maths
7  | 4         | science
8  | 4         | english


SELECT *
    FROM studentTB
    INNER JOIN studentCLUB
    ON studentTB.id = studentCLUB.studentID
    WHERE (club = 'maths') OR (club = 'science') OR (day = 'english')
    GROUP BY studentTB.id
```

This is what i have so far and it is selecting student when they fall within one of the club. But when i change the OR to AND it gives me null.
I will be glad if anyone can help me. Thank you

Comment: show us an additional  query where you try to use AND for better understanding of your problem

Comment: So you may have a student associated with multiple clubs ?

Comment: yes. the student can join more than one club

Answer (score 0):

So it you need to find students who belongs to all the given club you can do as below. It will check the students having all the given 3 clubs.

```
SELECT *
FROM studentTB
INNER JOIN studentCLUB
ON studentTB.id = studentCLUB.studentID
WHERE
club in ('maths','science','english') 
GROUP BY studentTB.id
having count(*) = 3
```

Comment: thanks, i not searching for student in all the three clubs. i want student who are in all the clubs selected - it can either maths ONLY or maths and science ONLY or maths and english ONLY or all the three.

Comment: Right , I suppose your clubs are user input and you can modify the above query by chaining the number of items inside in clause and then having part. For example if you say search `maths and science only` then  `in` clause would be `club in ('maths','science')` and finally `having count(*)=2`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM studentTB
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM studentCLUB
WHERE studentTB.id = studentCLUB.studentID)
```